# How do I implement CORS from IE11 using C# and JQuery.ajax?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm struggling to get CORS to work via IE11.

I have to make ajax requests using jquery (or with whatever the browser supports natively), no additional libraries. These requests are cross-domain and they work perfectly in Chrome and Firefox.

```
$.ajax(otherDomainConnectUrl, {
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        crossDomain: true,
        success: (connectParams, textStatus, jqxhr) => {
            console.log('Connect ok. Params: ', connectParams);
            success(connectParams);
        },
        error:  (jqxr, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
            this.errorRenderer.renderError(connectionError);
            console.log('jquery error results:', jqxr, textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

On the server-side I use ASP.NET MVC and C#. I do a CORS-check using a custom attribute on my controller action:

```
    [AllowCrossSiteJson]
    public string Connect()
    {
        // ... logic logic...
        var serializedMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(databag, settings);
        return serializedMessage;
    }
```

The CORS custom attribute has the following logic. Note how I retrieve a list of valid domains, then check if the Referrer URL is one of those domains, and then choose to accept/deny the CORS request:

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var allowedDomains = ClientSpecificConfig.GetAllowedHostDomains();

        if (filterContext?.RequestContext?.HttpContext?.Request?.UrlReferrer != null 
            && allowedDomains.Contains(filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.Host))
        {
            filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
            filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
```

So I only append Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* for known domains. I don't want to open the action to calls from absolutely any host anywhere.

The problem is that IE11 does not supply the Referrer at all, so I can't approve the CORS check by adding the necessary headers. So how do I check if the source host is a valid host when the script is running in IE11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE11 does not supply the Referrer for cross domain calls, but it does supply the Origin header.

I used this instead. The check for the "valid" source domain now looks as follows:

```
    private static bool sourceDomainIsAllowed(ActionExecutingContext filterContext, List<string> allowedDomains)
    {
        var request = filterContext?.RequestContext?.HttpContext?.Request;
        var referrerHost = request?.UrlReferrer?.Host;
        var originKey = request?.Headers.AllKeys.FirstOrDefault(k => k.EqualsIgnoreCase("Origin"));

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(referrerHost))
        {
            return allowedDomains.Contains(referrerHost);
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(originKey))
        {
            var origin = request.Headers[originKey];
            var uri = new Uri(origin);
            return allowedDomains.Contains(uri.Host);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom header with jQuery:

```
// Request with custom header
$.ajax({
    headers: { 'x-cors-auth': window.location.href }
});
```

From here you can set these headers to whatever value you want. Since IE isn't sending a referrer you can try actual setting the referrer header.

You can also use `$.ajaxSetup` to specify headers that will be sent on every request or you will be calling multiple domains you use before send:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        headers: { 'x-cors-auth': window.location.href }
    }
});
```